# List filtering through method calls

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am trying to create some sort of generic filtering system on my object model to allow for "staged" calls.

Consider the following model class which represents data in a database.

```
class MyClass
{
    public string PropertyA {get; set;}
    public string PropertyB {get; set;}
    public string PropertyC {get; set;}
    public string PropertyD {get; set;}
    public string PropertyE {get; set;}
}
```

I then have a DAL to retrieve the data..

```
public class MyClassDAL()
{
    public static List<MyClass> GetAllRequests()
    {
        List<MyClass> lst = new List<MyClass>();
        using (MyDBContext cntx = new MyDBContext())
        {
            lst = cntx.MyTable.ToList();
        }
        return (lst);
    }
}
```

At numerous points in my application, I need to be able to retrieve this data but depending on where in the application the request is made, I want to be able to filter on any of the model properties.

Now, I could pass in paramters, or set up lots of overloaded methods, but I would like to know if there was a more elegant and "code readable" way to do this..

Something like...

```
MyClassDAL.GetAllRequests().ForPropA("x")
                           .ForPropC("y")
                           .ForPropE("z")
```

Of course, I could just use LINQ `Where` Lambdas where ever i need it but was looking for a something a bit more "tidy"

Comment: Why do you think that MyClassDAL.GetAllRequests().Where(x=>x.PropertyA=="x") is unclear?

Comment: Consider `IQueryable`. http://blog.falafel.com/understanding-ienumerable-iqueryable-c/

Comment: Do you really want to read the *whole table* into memory before doing any filtering? I guess that's OK if there are only a few hundred rows, but still... that's not a good pattern for a DAL.

Comment: Using methods for filtering as in the example would mean method names would be bound to property names and each method would cover only one operator (equals). If another operator is required, such as 'not equal', the number of filtering methods would multiply by 2. With LINQ the expressive power of filtering conditions is much better.

Comment: No Gary, not really... being that its EF ... the SQL execution plan would be generated based on the filtering. I agree the DAL, at present, does a ToList() which will execute and retrieve all rows ... so that's where i need to change to IEnumerable/IQuearable etc so that the query plan can be built up prior to the final ToList() in the requesting module

Comment: Yes Martin, I agree... but in this case, the filtering is based on specific "equal to" values....

Answer (score 0):

If you use the linq Where function, you just need to provide it with a suitable expression, which doesn't have to be an anonymous function. You can define your own methods, like this:

```
    public static Expression<Func<MyEntity, bool>> NameIs(string name)
    {
        return e => e.Name == name;
    }
```

...and then call it like this:

```
    var x = context.MyEntities.Where(NameIs("foo"));
```

Or, you could use an extension method to get rid of the `Where` part:

```
    public static IQueryable<MyEntity> WhereNameIs(
        this IQueryable<MyEntity> entities,
        string name)
    {
        return entities.Where(e => e.Name == name);
    }
```

...which you could call as:

```
    var x = context.MyEntities.WhereNameIs("foo");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can customize this sorting solution, which works great for shorting. You need to pass parameters and generic method will do rest.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Data source
        List<Student> students = new List<Student>();
        students.Add(new Student { Id = 1, Name = "A" });
        students.Add(new Student { Id = 2, Name = "B" });
        students.Add(new Student { Id = 3, Name = "A" });
        students.Add(new Student { Id = 4, Name = "D" });

        // Apply Sorting
        var sorttedStudents = students.AsQueryable().ApplySort("id");
        var sorttedStudents1 = students.AsQueryable().ApplySort("-id");
        var sorttedStudents2 = students.AsQueryable().ApplySort("-name,id");

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public static class IQueryableApplyFilterExtension
{
    public static IQueryable<T> ApplySort<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, string key)
    {
        if (source == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("source", "Data source is empty.");
        }

        if (key == null)
        {
            return source;
        }

        var lstSort = key.Split(',');

        string sortExpression = string.Empty;

        foreach (var sortOption in lstSort)
        {
            if (sortOption.StartsWith("-"))
            {
                sortExpression = sortExpression + sortOption.Remove(0, 1) + " descending,";
            }
            else
            {
                sortExpression = sortExpression + sortOption + ",";
            }
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sortExpression))
        {
            // Note: Install-Package: system.linq.dynamic NuGet package is required here to operate OrderBy on string
            // Then use using System.Linq.Dynamic; namespace
            source = source.OrderBy(sortExpression.Remove(sortExpression.Count() - 1));
        }

        return source;
    }
}

public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Not really no... because you're sorting, not filtering